# eclipse Helios sorting - multiline warning description (gcc multiline warnings)

Tags: eclipse, gcc, eclipse-3.6, gcc-warning

I compile my project with gcc compiler. One of example multi line warning is:

```
../../Source/Ctrl/SCmd.h: In constructor `STCPCommand::STCPCommand(char)':
../../Source/Ctrl/SCmd.h:273: warning: `STCPCommand::m_pGroup' will be initialized  after
../../Source/Ctrl/SCmd.h:133: warning:   `const char*STCPCommand::m_pcszSourceInfo'
../../Source/Ctrl/SCmd.h:141: warning:   when initialized here
```

But I can't read it correctly in Problems view (Description). 
What I get is 3 different warnings. All lines are in different places - according to sort method.

Is there any way to show this output without sorting ?
Maybe there is some gcc flag that will avoid splitting ?